# Datatables AJAX request error

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, datatables

I am using DataTables with server-side processing with information from a form.
On form submit datatables sends a Ajax request, this request is handled by a Java Servlet.

After some problems I decided to start using Firebug. When I click on the submit button
firebug returns the following Jquery related error:

```
// Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

When I use Firebug to resend the request, the request is handled correctly, which means
that a JSON response is send to the browser.

I get a feeling there is something wrong with the order of the call, like the servlet isn't ready or something like that, this would explain why the re-send request succeeds. Altough I'm not certain.

DataTables jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchResults").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true
        });
    $('.searchsubmit').click(function() {
        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        $("#searchResults").dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": 'Search',
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "aoColumns": [
                          { "mDataProp": "messagecaseid" },
                          { "mDataProp": "messagesubject" },
                          { "mDataProp": "messagesender" },
                          { "mDataProp": "messagereceiver" }
                      ],
            "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                aoData.push({"name": "formData", "value": formData}
                        );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is 'Search' a valid URL? Also, the servlet could be sending back "valid JSON" that still can't be processed by DT. Could you post an example of the JSON being returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onClick method set the return value to false, so that the page doesn't refresh and Datatables gets a chance to populate the table.